# Vertically aligning single line text within a minimum height div

Tags: html, css, positioning, vertical-alignment

I have a certain class of `div` that contains an icon in the upper-left corner as the background image, and text in the remainder of the `div`. The `div` has a minimum height of 32px so that all of the icon is shown.

When there is multiple lines of text, the lines look fine as they stretch the `div` down longer than the minimum height, but when there is only one line, it is not vertically aligned with the centre of the icon.

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/eXZnH/15/).

Is there any way to get the single line to vertically align, but not mess it up when there are multiple lines?

```css
.test {
    background-color: #98c5ff;
    color: #093d80;
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 32px;
    background-image: url("http://google.com/favicon.ico");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 42px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"><p>Short message</p></div>
<hr />
<div class="test"><p>Rather long message that should hopefully wrap on to a second line at some point.</p></div>
<hr />
<div class="test"><p>Message<br />with<br />many<br />lines<br />.</p></div>
```

Comment: Not exactly, I don't want everything to be vertically aligned, only text that is smaller than the minimum height of the div.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `display` in your CSS like this:

```
.test {
    background-color: #999999;
    display: table; /* Add this in here. */
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 32px;
    background-image: url("http://google.com/favicon.ico");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 42px;
}

.test p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: While this does vertically align the text, it also causes the `div`s to not respect the width that I set.

Comment: The `.test` divs' width should be correct if you're explicitly stating the width as you seem to be. Here's the Fiddle adjusted with the widths set to 300px [http://jsfiddle.net/dsundy/eXZnH/21/](http://jsfiddle.net/dsundy/eXZnH/21/).

Comment: Ah, sorry. It was the comment in the above code that stopped it parsing the `width` line. Indeed it does work. Are there any downsides to using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`?

Comment: CSS tables aren't supported in IE 7 and below. But those people are probably seeing more odd things than text aligned to the top of divs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27520/discussion-between-danielgibbs-and-dsundy)

Answer (score 2):

`display:flex` is also an option for `.test`.

if `.test` holds a single `p` then `margin:auto 0;` should be enough:

http://jsfiddle.net/eXZnH/35/
EDIT: (fixed fiddle) http://jsfiddle.net/eXZnH/36/

```css
.test {
  background-color: #98c5ff;
  color: #093d80;
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 32px;
  background-image: url("http://google.com/favicon.ico");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 42px;
  display: flex;/* added */
}
p {
  margin: auto 0;/* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p>Short message</p>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="test">
  <p>Rather long message that should hopefully wrap on to a second line at some point.</p>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="test">
  <p>Message
    <br />with
    <br />many
    <br />lines
    <br />.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: IMHO your solution is "the right one" considering how the question was made. I was wrong as far as I considered the "aestetical issue" and not the question by itself... but I still likes more how my solution looks :) . (BTW the linked fiddle have wrong margin (just "0" spite of "auto 0"), fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/eXZnH/36/)

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing the position with `position:absolute;`

See fiddle: 
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eXZnH/30/)

Also here:
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="test"><p class="fix">Short message</p></div>
<hr />
<div class="test"><p>Rather long message that should hopefully wrap on to a second line at some point.</p></div>
<hr />
<div class="test"><p>Message<br />with<br />many<br />lines<br />.</p></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test {
    background-color: #98c5ff;
    color: #093d80;
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 32px;
    background-image: url("http://google.com/favicon.ico");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 42px;
}

.fix{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:390px;
}
```

You may need to modify the `bottom:390px` value even though I added div `container` to keep in place.

Answer (score 1):

As using display table may affect your width so I recommend to use sudo element`.test:after` to achieve vertical align you also could use `background-position` if you plan to align the icon vertically :

```css
.test {
background-color: #98c5ff;
color: #093d80;
width: 400px;
min-height: 32px;
background-image: url("http://google.com/favicon.ico");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-left: 42px;
   
}
.test:after{
content:"";
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
height:100%;
  
}
.test p{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="test"><p>Short message</p></div>
<hr />
<div class="test"><p>Rather long message that should hopefully wrap on to a second line at some point.</p></div>
<hr />
<div class="test"><p>Message<br />with<br />many<br />lines<br />.</p></div>
```

Updated you fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eXZnH/33/)

Answer (score 1):

Not really centering, but visually centering and keeping consitency:
Padding top could solve it, but the amount will depend on the line height and the font size.

```
.test p:first-child{padding-top:8px}
```

On the othe hand, if you don't mind to change the line height of muti-line divs you could set line-height for the "p" elements to fit the div height.

```
.test {line-height:32px}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eXZnH/34/

Answer (score 1):

Even easier, would be to use ::before within CSS

```
.test {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 32px;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

.test::before {
  content: url(http://google.com/favicon.ico);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -16px; /* image height divided by 2 */
}
```

Check it out man

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 32px;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

.test::before {
  content: url(http://google.com/favicon.ico);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<p>
bla bla bla<br />
bla bla bla<br />
bla bla bla<br />
bla bla bla<br />
bla bla bla<br />
</p>
</div>

<div class="test">
<p>bla bla bla bla</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all you are using *hr* tags after each div therefore you can not align them. So first delete them and then add these styles to *.test* class

```
.test {
   // another styles..
   width: 130px; //small width for test
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```